# Why does DNU publish not correctly publish wrapped projects?

Tags: asp.net, dnu

I'm trying to `dnu publish` an ASP.NET RC1 web application which references a "wrapped" .NET 4.5.1 class library. When I publish it, a folder for the wrapped project is included in the output packages directory but it only contains a project.json file whose paths refer to the original source directory. No dlls are published for the wrapped project. Is this a known issue?

This is the command I'm using:

`dnu publish src\MyProject --out packaged --runtime active`